# File Handling in Java - Adding a text at alternate lines in a file

Tags: java, file

I want to write a Java program that takes the input of a text file, and adds a text line after every line present in it.
For example, if the file contains the following content :

- 1 line
- 2 line
- 3 line

The ouput must be :

- 1 line
- Hello World
- 2 line
- Hello World
- 3 line
- Hello World

(ignore the bullet points)

I encountered this question in an interview and was clueless. I thought iterating through the file line by line and every time we encounter a new line, we can append the "Hello World" string. I do not know how to put it into code. I am a beginner and just learning.

Comment: Did you get what you were interviewing for?

Comment: To do that, you have to create a new file. Your program should read the old file line-by-line. Each time a line is read, it is written to the new file, followed by the "Hello World" line. Someone has to specify what the program should do after the loop exits. Should the old file be deleted, and the new file saved with the old file's name?  Should the new file be saved with a name that indicates a version, such as `oldFile(2).txt`?

Comment: An alternative is to read the entire contents of the file into memory, and then write back with the new data.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I was informed that the changes must be made to the same file, so I am assuming deleting the old file and renaming it with the old file's name could work out in the end. I need to put it in code and check, which is where I am finding the difficulty. I will try that and get back.

Comment: You can search Stack Overflow to see if this question has been asked and answered in a way that helps you:  https://www.google.com/search?q=adding+lines+middle+of+file+in+java+site%3A+stackoverflow.com&

Comment: Not what you are asking for, but if it is a one-time job and you happen to have a linux box with bash, you can do **cat test.txt | sed 's/$/\nHello World/'**

Comment: The problem with reading a line, and writing it back with the "Hello World" line appended is that the writing back will write over part of what follows the line just read.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I thought iterating through the file line by line and every time we encounter a new line, we can append the "Hello World" string. I do not know how to put it into code. ...'*

Utilize the *[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html)* or *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class, both of which provide convenient *[readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())*, and *[nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())*, methods.

Here is an example.

```java
String fs = "file.txt", s;
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fs))) {
    while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
        l.add(s);
        l.add("Hello World");
    }
}
try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(fs)) {
    for (String v : l) w.println(v);
    w.flush();
}
```

And, here is an example using *streams*.

```java
String s = "file.txt";
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s))) {
    r.lines()
     .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x, "Hello World"))
     .forEachOrdered(l::add);
}
try (PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(s)) {
    l.forEach(w::println);
    w.flush();
}
```